# Do light field cameras exist?

Tags: photography

A company called [Lytro](http://www.lytro.com/) claim to be producing a light-field camera that has a key feature that the focus point can be moved after the image has been taken.

Their claims have been questioned by [jwz](http://www.jwz.org/blog/2011/06/lytro/), a well-known blogger who says he can't understand how their diagram/explanation makes any sense. He points out that it includes lenses, which are about discarding  the very information about light fields the company claims to capture.

The web-site includes some demonstrations which would be moderately easy to fake (Take the original shot with a [Frazier lens](http://www.petapixel.com/2011/04/19/frazier-ultimate-lens-shows-everything-in-focus-with-massive-depth-of-field/), and then blur selective parts afterwards, or lots of photos of each layer photoshopped together.)

The web-site notably does *not* include any photographs of a prototype product.

The CEO, [Dr Ren Ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren_Ng) won the [2006 ACM Doctoral Dissertation Award](http://www.acm.org/press-room/news-releases-2007/internal/) for his research in the area. (Note: It was awarded in 2007, which explains some discrepancies about the award date.)

Is this a real product being developed? A fake? Or is there another option?

Comment: We might not know until one comes out (supposedly this year), but for any interested, [HERE](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/lfcamera/lfcamera-150dpi.pdf) is his Stanford thesis with many examples, a shot of what looks like a "prototype" and an explanation of how it works. There's also [THIS](http://k9ventures.com/blog/2011/06/22/the-making-of-lytro/) post form a colleague and funding partner. Appears legit on the surface of it to me!

Comment: The german company [Raytrix](http://www.raytrix.de/index.php/models.html) is already selling light field cameras. But according to this [Yahoo Tech News article](http://news.yahoo.com/s/yblog_technews/20110622/tc_yblog_technews/new-cameras-use-thousands-of-lenses-to-let-you-focus-after-shooting) Lytro's camera will probably be much cheaper.

Comment: The point about lenses is true (focal plane) but nobody said that the lens can’t be re-adjusted so as to record multiple focal planes.

Comment: @Hendy, thanks for the useful link. @Oliver, that looks like a conclusive answer, rather than a comment. Want to make it so?

Comment: 6.5 years later, and [Lytro Cinema](https://www.lytro.com/cinema) is "only available to select partners in North America at this time." making its vapourware status still unclear.

Comment: quite right, @Oddthinking !

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Light field cameras exist, and they are *awesome*. I remember first hearing about this a few years ago from Adobe, as they had done a bunch of research into it for future Photoshop use, in creating software that could properly work with plenoptic images. ([Plenoptic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plenoptic_camera) is another word for light-field.) However, there's still certainly plenty of evidence that this is the real deal:

- [Ren Ng's original Stanford site](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/lfcamera/) about the camera project.
- From that website, [the tech report about the research](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/lfcamera/lfcamera-150dpi.pdf) (Hendy linked to this).
- Also from that website, [a video demonstration and explanation](http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/lfcamera/lfcamera.avi) (this is incredible).
- [A New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/22/technology/22camera.html?_r=1) from just a few days ago talking about it, which reveals that he's received $50 million in venture capital backing... quite a lot to put in if the investors aren't confident there's something there. And it should be a pretty public announcement. From the article:

  > [Ng] thinks a popular use may be families and friends roaming through different perspectives on pictures of, say, vacations and parties posted on Facebook (Lytro will have a Facebook app).
- [An article from Wired](http://www.wired.com/science/discoveries/news/2005/11/69594) in 2005 when Ng was still a grad student talking about the early stages of the development.
- And [an article from Popular Science](http://www.popsci.com/gadgets/article/2011-05/cameras-40000-lenses-help-salvage-blurry-images) about Raytrix, the German company that Oliver_C mentioned. Problem here is one needs to request prices on their cameras on their websites, though Popsci apparently went and did that, to the tune of $30,000. Good money on Ng's being cheaper.

This technology has amazing applications, though. It basically is the [Enhance Button](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EnhanceButton)!

Comment: Never heard of this technology before, but I'm looking forward to it now!